# Is it possible to pass generic protocols into a constructor for proper Dependency Injection in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, generics, dependency-injection, swift-protocols

I am trying to accomplish protocol oriented programming in Swift 3 using generics. Is this not fully supported yet? I'm going to show you what I would LIKE to do below but will not compile. Am I missing something here? My goal is to be able to use protocol oriented programming to perform dependency injection with the intent of easily mocking these structures in my unit tests.

```
protocol ZombieServiceProtocol {

    func fetchZombies()
    var zombieRepository: RepositoryProtocol<Zombie> { get set }
}

struct ZombieService: ZombieServiceProtocol {

    var zombieRepository: RepositoryProtocol<Zombie>

    init(zombieRepository: RepositoryProtocol<Zombie>) {
        self.zombieRepository = zombieRepository
    }

    func fetchZombies() {
        self.zombieRepository.deleteAll()
        self.createFakeZombies()
    }

    private func createFakeZombies() {
        for index in 1...100 {
            let zombie = Zombie(id: index, name: "Zombie \(index)")
            self.zombieRepository.insert(zombie)
        }
    }
}
```

The Zombie class looks like this:

```
public struct Zombie: Persistable {

    var id: Int
    let name: String?
    init(id: Int, name: String?) {
            self.id = id
            self.name =name
    }
}
```

Its Persistable protocol looks like this:

```
protocol Persistable {  
    var id: Int { get set }
}
```

And my Repository code looks something like this:

```
protocol RepositoryProtocol: class {
    associatedtype Object: Persistable

    //...

    func insert(_ object: Object) -> Void
    func deleteAll(_ predicate: (Object) throws -> Bool) -> Void
}

class Repository<Object: Persistable>: RepositoryProtocol {

    var items = Array<Object>()

    //...

    func insert(_ object: Object) {
        self.items.append(object)
    }

    func deleteAll() {
        self.items.removeAll()
    }

}
```

I get the following error in my ZombieServiceProtocol:

- Cannot specialize non-generic type 'RepositoryProtocol'

I get the following error in my ZombieService:

- Cannot specialize non-generic type 'RepositoryProtocol'
- Member 'insert' cannot be used on value of protocol type
  'RepositoryProtocol'; use a generic constraint instead

And to highlight exactly what I'm trying to accomplish, here is what a simple test would look like in which I create a Mock repository and attempt to use that instead of the real one in my ZombieService:

```
@testable import ZombieInjection
class ZombieServiceTests: XCTestCase {

    private var zombieRepository: RepositoryProtocol<Zombie>!
    private var zombieService: ZombieServiceProtocol

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
        self.zombieRepository = RepositoryMock<Zombie>()
        self.zombieService = ZombieService(zombieRepository: self.zombieRepository)
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testExample() {
        // Arrange
        // Act
        self.zombieService.fetchZombies()

        // Assert
        XCTAssert(self.zombieRepository.count() > 0)
    }
}
```

This code also does not compile presently with the same errors as above.

I have been looking at the associatedTypes and typeAlias tags as well as the [Generics Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md). While looking at the Manifesto, I believe this falls into the "Generic Protocols" section which is currently marked as Unlikely (which is bumming me out). If I can't accomplish something like I'm trying to do above, what would be the next best solution?

Comment: Looking like a resounding no? Going to try and refactor to see what else I can do...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes it is definitely possible, just that it currently requires some PAT-related "magic". With Swift3 and Xcode 8.0 beta 4, you should be able to run the following in a playground:

```
protocol Persistable {
    var id: Int { get set }
}
protocol RepositoryProtocol: class {
    associatedtype Object: Persistable
    func insert(_ object: Object) -> Void
    func deleteAll()
}
protocol ZombieServiceProtocol {
    associatedtype RepositoryType: RepositoryProtocol
    var zombieRepository: RepositoryType { get set }
    func fetchZombies()
}
public struct Zombie: Persistable {
    var id: Int
    let name: String?
}

// Mocks
class RepositoryMock<Object: Persistable>: RepositoryProtocol {
    func insert(_ object: Object) { print("look, there's another one!")}
    func deleteAll() { print("it's safe out there, all zombies have been deleted") }
}
struct ZombieServiceMock<RepositoryType: RepositoryProtocol
                    where RepositoryType.Object == Zombie>: ZombieServiceProtocol {
    var zombieRepository: RepositoryType
    init(zombieRepository: RepositoryType) {
        self.zombieRepository = zombieRepository
    }
    func fetchZombies() {
        self.zombieRepository.deleteAll()
        self.createMockZombies()
    }
    private func createMockZombies() {
        for index in 1...5 {
            let zombie = Zombie(id: index, name: "Zombie \(index)")
            self.zombieRepository.insert(zombie)
        }
    }
}

// Tests
class ZombieServiceTests<RepositoryType: RepositoryProtocol,
                         ServiceType: ZombieServiceProtocol
                                where ServiceType.RepositoryType == RepositoryType> {
    private var zombieRepository: RepositoryType
    private var zombieService: ServiceType

    init(repository: RepositoryType, service: ServiceType) {
        zombieRepository = repository
        zombieService = service
    }
    func testExample() {
        self.zombieService.fetchZombies()
    }
}
let repositoryMock = RepositoryMock<Zombie>()
let repositoryService = ZombieServiceMock(zombieRepository: repositoryMock)
let zombieTest = ZombieServiceTests(repository: repositoryMock, service: repositoryService)
zombieTest.testExample()

// Prints:
// it's safe out there, all zombies have been deleted
// look, there's another one!
// look, there's another one!
// look, there's another one!
// look, there's another one!
// look, there's another one!
```

Comment: This has gotten me much closer to what I want! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do in current Swift is to replace (non-working) generic protocols with generic non-final classes. Example:

```
class RepositoryBase<Object: Persistable> {
    func insert(_ object: Object) -> Void {
        fatalError()
    }
    func deleteAll(_ predicate: (Object) throws -> Bool) -> Void {
        fatalError()
    }
}

struct ZombieService: ZombieServiceProtocol {
    var zombieRepository: RepositoryBase<Zombie>
    // ...
}
```

Such code is likely to be non-idiomatic in Swift (stub methods in base class), but it works.

Comment: I was really trying to avoid this kind of work... Going to try the other answer for now.